# React Native: Error: While trying to resolve module `fs` from file

Tags: react-native

Code lines causing the problem:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: './Key.json', // I guess this line.
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
});

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
```

and Error:

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: While trying to resolve module `fs` from file `C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src\discovery.js`, the package `C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\fs\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\fs\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\fs\index.js(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\fs\index.js\index(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:243:17)
    at C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async visit (C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async visit (C:\Users\berk-yavuz\Documents\SW\Barcin-Mobile-App-main\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 10)
```

How can i solve this problem?

I tried make a variable instead of a path but doesn't worked.